# What are the options to create a graph database from URL manually?

Tags: nosql, neo4j, graph-databases

So i have to subjectively/ manually copy a number of URLs. I will then map out the relationships between these URLs by links. I can do this by pasting the links in a 
Graph database like neo4j, Infogrid etc.

However is there a way to simplify and implement the same using some other tools online. The problem is as this process would be repeated over a long time and many relationships would be constantly created i find pasting the links and creating so many relationships offline would be cumbersome and time consuming.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: So you are searching for something like Neoclipse running in a web-browser? Are you familiar with the WebAdmin - features from the neo4j - community package? Maybe this is what you searching for...

Comment: Thank you for your reply and yes that is something i am looking for, i will check the webadmin features

Comment: A tool for linking URL's automatically would have to be written by hand, you can ask on the neo4j google grop for help writing one or if someone would be interested to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite following what you wanna do. Are you building a simple graph, or trying something like RDF? For the latter, there is a SPARQL plugin for Neo4j in the making, please look at https://github.com/peterneubauer/sparql-plugin/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/server/plugin/sparql/SPARQLPluginFunctionalTest.java for an example.

Comment: Hello , I am trying to build a simple graph , but i would like to do it easily and intuitively in the browser